# List pages in a category on a parent page

Tags: php, wordpress

Tearing my hair out trying to do this. First off I need to display the child pages (with a link and a thumbnail) on the parent page which i have figured out. The problem is that these child pages fall in to two categories "Current" and "Past". So i found some code which allows you to add categories to pages (as you can't by default in wordpress) but i can't figure out how to add something to the code below to only show pages in certain categories (i guess an if and else would work, its just querying the categories)

Here is the code i am using to show the thumbnails and title:

```
<?php
$mypages = get_pages( array( 'child_of' => $post->ID, 'sort_column' => 'post_date', 'sort_order' => 'desc' ) );

foreach( $mypages as $page ) {      ?>
            <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $page->ID ); ?>
    <h2><a href="/<?php echo get_page_link( $page->ID ); ?>"><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></a></h2>
<?php
}   
?>
```

Here is the code i found that adds categories to pages:

```
function myplugin_settings() {  
// Add tag metabox to page
register_taxonomy_for_object_type('post_tag', 'page'); 
// Add category metabox to page
register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'page');  
}
// Add to the admin_init hook of your theme functions.php file 
add_action( 'admin_init', 'myplugin_settings' );
```

Thank you anyone who can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get the categories by page id then check your category with the page categories

```
<?php
$mypages = get_pages(array('child_of' => $post->ID, 'sort_column' => 'post_date', 'sort_order' => 'desc'));

foreach ($mypages as $page) {
    $category = get_the_category($page->ID);
    $categories = array();
    foreach ($category  as $c) {
        $categories[] = $c->cat_name;
    }

    if (in_array("your category name",$categories)){
        ?>
        <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID); ?>
        <h2><a href="/<?php echo get_page_link($page->ID); ?>"><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></a></h2>
    <?php
    }

}
?>
```

**EDIT**

```
<?php
$mypages = get_pages(array('child_of' => $post->ID, 'sort_column' => 'post_date', 'sort_order' => 'desc'));
?>    

<h1>Category 1</h1>
<?php foreach ($mypages as $page) {
    $category = get_the_category($page->ID);
    $categories = array();
    foreach ($category  as $c) {
        $categories[] = $c->cat_name;
    }    
    if (in_array("Category 1",$categories)){
        ?>
        <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID); ?>
        <h2><a href="/<?php echo get_page_link($page->ID); ?>"><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></a></h2>
    <?php
    }
}
?>
<h1>Category 2</h1>
<?php foreach ($mypages as $page) {
    $category = get_the_category($page->ID);
    $categories = array();
    foreach ($category  as $c) {
        $categories[] = $c->cat_name;
    }    
    if (in_array("Category 2",$categories)){
        ?>
        <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID); ?>
        <h2><a href="/<?php echo get_page_link($page->ID); ?>"><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></a></h2>
    <?php
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, i have tried it but i can't get it to show anything unfortunately.

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct category name in above code **"your category name"**

Comment: Yep, i am using the category slug. I have tried it with and without quotes but nothing show up

Comment: i have put a condition with category name , not with category slug

Comment: Sorry i should have made my previous reply clearer. I tried with both slug and category name but still doing get anything (both inside and out of quotes) i added in an else "else {
echo "sausage";
}" which shows up so it seems it is working, just not locating the category

Comment: @user3115441 my bad i have looped the empty array see my updated answer `foreach ($category ..`

Comment: That works, fantastic thank you. Two get the two categories i just duplicated the if and made it an else if - is that the correct way? Sorry i have one more question, if i wanted to add a title for each of the categories how would i do that. I tried adding it in the loop but then it showed for each of the items